# creating WPF user control with no interface

Tags: wpf, user-controls

I would like to create a user control that you can drag and drop from the tool box to your XAML but that has not interface at all. I was used to do it for timers and background workers and this kind of elements.

So you allow users to drag into their projects and then set the name and other properties through the properties panel, attach functions to events in the event panel and they may perform almost all the set up without writing a single line of code (some customers love that)

Is that even possible ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "Component" type class like you might have used in WinForms, etc. However, you can probably just derive from FrameworkElement. By default it does no rendering so nothing will show up and as long as you don't set any Margins, MinWidth, etc. it shouldn't affect the layout really either. You might be able to derive from UIElement but using FrameworkElement will mean your object will have access to the DataContext so properties on it can be bound to things on it.

Comment: I had no time to test .. but your answer has all the sense in the world heheh